# Laptop restarts with blue screen with error 0x00001d8

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, bsod, crash

My Lenovo U31-70, is restarting with a blue screen with printed "error 0x00001d8", normally when i have the pc on for a couple of hours, like 3 hours, and when it happens it returns to happen if don't power off the pc for hours or entire night...

I guess the problem is intensive use, but when it happens pc is not hot, i have another pc (gaming pc OMEN from HP) and it almost fries my skin, but neither shuts down neither blue screen...

**So how can i reolve the problem and what is casuing it exactly?**

I don0t want my pc rebooting every time...

I already reinstalled Windows (the longer way in "settings, recover...") 2 times and the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

This post on Microsoft may help! -> [Click Me!](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/laptop-keeps-popping-up-error-code-0x000001d8-and/f1c098f1-c144-4ce7-89dd-dfd6830dedee?auth=1)

Comment: How isn't working, i can hear it... if wasn't working keyboard would be warm at least... when i say "is not hot"  mean the laptopt itself not the air that comes out... Thanks Anyway